# What kind of construction is employed in the word "six-wheeler"?

Tags: suffixes

What is the connection between the fact a vehicle has six wheels and the suffix "er" in "six-wheeler" and the suffix "er" in three-pointer?

Is it grammatically correct to use the "er" suffix like that, or is it just street language?

Comment: [**-er, entry 5**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/er): 1b, *person or thing belonging to or associated with*; 1d, *one that has*; 1e, *one that produces or yields*

Comment: [Four-wheeler](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/four-wheeler) is a _grammatically_ correct term for a vehicle with four wheels.

Comment: Note that although it's fine to use [***a three-wheeler***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+three-wheeler&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20three%20-%20wheeler%3B%2Cc0) as a "condensed" version of ***a three-wheeled vehicle***, it's not remotely idiomatic to derive ***a four-legger*** from ***a four-legged animal***, even though *semantically*, both examples are making exactly the same shift. So don't make too many assumptions about using this construction in other contexts.

Comment: Oh - and *He's a six-footer* doesn't normally mean he has six feet (One at the end of each leg? Only if he's an *insect!* :)  It means he's ***six feet tall***.

Comment: There is no 'rule' that enables you to always make a correctly formed '-er' word. Rather, you just learn the ones that you hear or read.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix -er is used in various constructions to form nouns that have some characteristic.  You probably know the use of -er to form agent nouns "builder = a person that builds"

They are also used with number-unit expressions to form nouns characterised by that amount.

> nine-footer = something that is nine feet long, (eg a boat)

> first grader = someone in the first grade of school

"Six-wheeler" follows this use, as does "three-pointer".  This is correct grammar.

But it might be fairly informal, as it assumes you understand what kind of thing you are talking about.  If you say "What is she -- a 24-footer?" You could be talking about [boats or snakes](https://www.reddit.com/r/herpetology/comments/kkfd9y/far_side_herp_humor/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

So "six-wheeler", like other short forms, tends to be more casual than a longer but clearer "six-wheel truck". Likewise "three-pointer" compared to "three-point shot".

And there is no guarantee that a particular example has much actual use.  As mentioned in comments, "four-footer" would not an idiomatic way to refer to an animal with four feet.

Comment: how about "weekender"? I mean it is not optional that someone won't go through weekender, so how to distinct the "weekender" situations?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @thonyalbuquerque — a “weekender” is someone who is only in a particular place (e.g. a seaside vacation town) for the weekend.  “This cottage is perfect for  weekenders.” 
Obviously, all of us will continue to exist somewhere during that weekend.

Comment: I suggest you read through all the examples in the [Wiktionary definiotn of -er](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er#Etymology_1)  "six-wheeler" is sense 4, and "weekender" is sense 5.

Comment: @all, based on that source: "https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/-er#:~:text=1%20%2Der-,%2F%C9%9A%2F,faster" what would the "three-pointer" be most related?

Comment: it is in the form "number+unit-er" so very obviously sense 4 of the Wiktionary definition.